# combining price and government taxes

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have several files that are provided.
I can convert and put them in an array, however, i cant figure out how to compare the 2 arrays:

1 is the product information and pricing
eg:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
      [Description] => description 
      [ArtID] => 1111 
      [PartID] => 1111 
      [Price] => 8.59 
      [Stock] => 24 [ 
   ) 
   [1] => Array ( 
      [Description] => ....
```

the other contains all items that contain a certain type of government tax.

what i need to do is have array2, with the government tax, looped to match partid in array1, then have array1's price updated with old price + tax ..

the values in array2 don't contain all items (not all items are subject to the tax),
and it does not contain the same amount of fields (less info required)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ccnt = count($product_arr);
for($c=0;$c<$ccnt;$c++){
  $price_original = $product_arr['price'];
  $price = $product_arr['price'];
  if(isset($gov_arr['tax'])){ $price = $price + ($price * $gov_arr['tax']); } // if percent
  $product_arr[$c]['price'] = $price;
  $product_arr[$c]['price_orig'] = $price_original;
}
```

Basically loop through the products and see if gov_arr['tax'] exist. If does then do math to get new value and then replace. I also saved the original price so if needed.

Comment: the problem here would be that you assume both arrays are similar.
but, in fact it can be more like in the prices array you have item-price, item2-price2, item3-price3 while in the tax array you might encounter item7-tax7, item2-price2, item4-price4 ...

Comment: true, they would have check all of those but at least it is a start int he right direction. Without the complete both arrays its hard to give a full answer.